# how to use button insert a word after the same textfield by jquery

Tags: jquery, button, click, textfield

I want to type something in a textfield and click a button,and it paste some words,

just like a paste button ,but always paste the same word after the same textfield ,

this is my code,my opinion is when I click the button ,focus is gone so I use blur,
its wrong, anybody know how to do?

```
$('#but1').click(function(){
    $('#table1 :text').blur(function(){
        var h = 'test'; 
        $(this).val(h+$(this).val());
    });
});

<table id="table1" >
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="text1" size="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="text2" size="30"></td>
    </tr>       
</table>
<input type="button" value="button" id="but1">
```

sorry ,I have wrong type here,in my jsp the select ID is correct.

Comment: why are you waiting for the blur functionality within your button`s click event ? . this way it will not work. just paste the code within onblur() call within click event of your button, then remove the onblur() event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="button" id="but1">
```

Your id is `but1` but in the JS you have `$('#bu1').click(function(){`

Correct it as `$('#but1').click(function(){`

Are you trying to get the `#text1`'s value to `#text2` prepending `h = 'test'` with it.

If so try this

```
$('#but1').click(function () {
    var h = 'test';
    var value = $("#text1").val();
    $("#text2").val(h + value);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7z3kc/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#bu1').click(function(){
```

should be

```
$('#but1').click(function(){
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b7uZc/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/q22Hp/)

```
$('#but1').click(function () {
    //$('#table1 :text').blur(function () {
        //var h = 'test';
        //$(this).val(h + $(this).val());
    //});
    var txt = $('#text1').val();
    $('#text2').val(txt);
});
```

By the way you use `$('#bu1')`. not the same with your button id.

Just use clicked. Don't make things more complicated.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

there are few logical errors in your code, i have refined it

**JS CODE:**

```
$('#but1').click(function () {
  //$('#table1 :text').blur(function(){ //commented out
  var target = $('#table1 :text'); //added newly
  var newTxt = 'test';
  target.val(newTxt + target.val());
  //}); //commented out
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/KmkTs/

Happy Coding:)